# InvalidKeyException while wrapping and unwrapping using RSA algorithm

Tags: java, exception, rsa, encryption

I am new to Java and want to wrap a symmetric key using RSA algorithm. In my case I am not generating the public key for wrapping, but retrieving the public key from Microsoft Keystore.

```
// Encrypt the generated Symmetric AES Key using RSA cipher     
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", 
       ks.getProvider().getName()); rsaCipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, RSAPubKey);
byte[] encryptedSymmKey = rsaCipher.wrap(aeskey);
```

I am getting an InvalidKeyException as shown below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key type: Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 171871587533146191561538456391418351861663300588728159334223437391061141885590024223283480319626015611710315581642512941578588886825766256507714725820048129123720143461110410353346492039350478625370269565346566901446816729164309038944197418238814947654954590754593726047828813400082450341775203029183105860831
  public exponent: 65537
    at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.init(RSACipher.java:176)
    at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.engineInit(RSACipher.java:129)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sap.srm.crpto.client.applet.CryptoClass.main(CryptoClass.java:102)
```

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestion how to use the SunMSCAPI appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

As the error message tells you, you are using a `Sun RSA public key`. That implies that regardless of how you retrieve the public key (the code is not provided, so I don't know) it is not associated with the MSCAPI key store. My guess is you take the public key from a certificate. So one way to solve your problem is to use the Sun provider `Cipher` class, too, for wrapping the AES key:

```
Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
rsaCipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, RSAPubKey);
byte[] encryptedSymmKey = rsaCipher.wrap(aeskey);
```

So in this case, there's no need to use the MSCAPI for achieving your goal - you can use the standard providers.